# change feed data in databricks

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

How can I pass the lateste version as startingVersion and evndingVersion while Im trying to read changeFeed data in databricks?

Code I have

```
df1 = spark.read.format("delta") \
.option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
.option("startingVersion", 45) \
.option("endingVersion", 45) \
.table("mdp_prd.bronze.nrq_customerassetproperty_autoloader_nodups")
```

goal is to dont hardcode `startingVersion` and `endingVersion` nor, to use the somekind of watermark table. But is there some built it options to this feature that it autoamticlly detects the last version of the `_commit_version` value?

P.S streaming is not the option too.

Comment: you need latest delta version?

Comment: I think its different then what I need

Answer (score 0):

you can use `describe history` to get latest version for
changeFeed.

Code.

```
maxi = spark.sql("select  max(version) as maxi from (describe  history your_table)").collect()[0][0]
df1 = spark.read.format("delta") \
.option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
.option("startingVersion", maxi) \
.option("endingVersion", maxi) \
.table("your_table")
display(df1)
```

Output:

**9** is the latest commit version in my table.

[image]